# Nested Quantifiers Doubt: "If $xy$ is equal to $x$ for all $y$, then $x=0$"

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

If $P(x,y,z)$ represents $xy=z$.
Then represent the following statement using quantifiers,connectives etc.
"If $xy$ is equal to $x$ for all $y$, then $x=0$".

The answer given is  $\forall x[ \forall y P(x,y,x)\to x=0]$.

Can't we write the same as: $\forall x\forall y[P(x,y,x)\to x=0]$.

Please help me out when can I take the quantified variables outside and when can I not.

Comment: In fact, I find your answer better than the given one..

Comment: "If xy is equal to x for all y,then x=0" - This isn't a statement, $x$ isn't quantified. The correct answer would be $\forall y(xy=x)\to x=0$.

Comment: At least for me, your quantifiers won't load: they're just empty rectangles. Consider using dollar signs and \-commands: `$\forall x[\forall y \, P(x, y, x) = 0 \rightarrow x = 0]$` gives $\forall x[\forall y \, P(x, y, x) = 0 \rightarrow x = 0]$.

Comment: @Arthur For a quick fix try another browser or maybe [edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1337418/edit) the question to see the text.

Comment: @GitGud I was hesitant to edit, partly because I am completely uncertain about what quantifiers are used. I assume what I wrote is one of the two expressions, but I have no idea about the other. And when I press to edit, all I see are squares that have question marks in them instead of being empty. As for other browser, are you certain you want this site to require certain browsers over others? I can't be the only one using the browser I'm using. Shouldn't it be equally available to all independent of which browser one uses?

Comment: @Arthur I was hoping that you'd be able to visualize the symbols in the edit page, that was my intent. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @GitGud Well, no such luck. Apparently, chrome just doesn't accept those character codes at all (that might be som locale setting, though).

Comment: @Arthur I'm on Chrome, Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two claims aren't equivalent (as Arthur explains). Which just goes to show that you have to be careful moving quantifiers around -- especially when extracting them from the antecedents of conditionals (where there are in effect hidden negation signs waiting to trip you up!).

To simplify the case for the moment, let's note first that $[\forall yRy \to p]$ is NOT equivalent to $\forall y[Ry \to p]$. In fact, assuming the proposition $p$ doesn't contain the variable $y$, we have:

$$[\forall yRy \to p] \Leftrightarrow [\neg\forall yRy \lor p] \Leftrightarrow [\exists y \neg Ry \lor p]\Leftrightarrow \exists y[ \neg Ry \lor p] \Leftrightarrow \exists y[Ry \to p]$$

Here the quantifier move is ok: Can you see why $[\exists yQy \lor p]$ IS equivalent to $\exists y[Qy \lor p]$?

So in fact $\forall x[\forall yP(x,y,x) \to x = 0]$ -- which is indeed the correct answer -- is equivalent, if you want to export the quantifier -- to $\forall x\exists y[P(x,y,x) \to x = 0].$

This sort of thing will be explained in any elementary text book. I see that P-t-r Sm-th's super *Introduction to Formal Logic* does it in §24.3 on Moving Quantifiers :-).

Answer (score 3):

No, that is not the same at all.

- The first expression says is that for any $x$, the statement "For any $y$ we have $xy = x$" implies the statement "$x = 0$".
- The second expression says that for any $x$ and $y$, the statement "$xy = x$" implies the statement "$x = 0$".

The second expression isn't true, and particulary the case $y = 1$ throws a wrench in the works, since in that case $xy = x$ holds also for values of $x$ which aren't $0$.